# Is there any rest API to get ratings from a public Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web application that gets information from different platforms which is working fine. I want to get ratings of a public Facebook page without login and without any access token using javascript. Is there any rest API or open API which can help me get these ratings without all heck of login and access token ?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

> A Page Access Token is required for all methods.

That means, you have to manage the Page if you want to get the ratings with the API. There is no way to get ratings for any public Page if you don´t manage it.